# Problem with malformed Bundle when deploying to iOS 13 with Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm having trouble deploying my application to iOS 13. It is presenting the error message

> malformed bundle does not contain an identifier at /library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/WatchOS4.1.simruntime An error was encoutered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2)

Has anyone had the same error and managed to resolve it? Or do you know how I can solve it?

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 Rio.

Comment: Please, put the message here in text format, not in a picture.

Comment: Deploying to a real device? I'm surprised that it's referencing WatchOS

Comment: I am deploying in a simulator.

Comment: You won't be able to run it in a WatchOS simulator, and if you want to use an iOS simulator, you will need to use one that is version 10.3 or less, which will run only on macOS 10.14 or less. If you are able to obtain a real device, it would be far easier.